# Encryption and Decryption using RSA publick key?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How to encrypt/decrypt password using `RSA Public Key` in windows store application. Any example or sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out MSDN sample of CryptoWinRT.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CryptoWinRT-sample-0d74f26b)

This sample shows how to use the new Cryptography APIs.

Specifically, this sample shows how to use:

- The CryptographicBuffer class to convert and encode strings
- The HashAlgorithmProvider class
- Supported Hash algorithms
- The MacAlgorithmProvider class
- Supported HMAC algorithms
- The KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider class
- The SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider class
- Supported symmetric algorithms
- The EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData class
- Supported authenticated encryption algorithms
- The AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider class
- Supported asymmetric algorithms
- The AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider class
- Supported signature algorithms
- The DataProtectionProvider class

Comment: I browsed through few examples, all creating their own private/public key. But i have public key and need to use that to encrypt/decrypt. Any idea?

Comment: If you have key already then you can use [AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.ImportKeyPair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.importkeypair.aspx) instead of [AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.CreateKeyPair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.createkeypair(v=win.10).aspx). I think scenario 7 from MSDN sample will help you.